# recently viewed items stack: Add a configuration option for MAX_ITEMS in Recent.php

Tags: developer

What's the recommended way to make the max item count of civi's recently viewed items stack configurable. Current value ist a constant `MAX_ITEMS` defined directly in `CRM/Utils/Recent.php`.

A quick glance at `civicrm.settings.php` lets me think that this is not the right place – stuff there seems to be more generic/low level.

Maybe it's possible to add a new field in `admin/setting/misc` (`CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Miscellaneous`)?

So where to put this?

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail?  I'm not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to implement a configuration option "recent_items_max_count" which adjusts the size of civi's last-viewed-items stack. I'm wondering where to store configuration options like this.
The civicrm.settings.php seems to hold more basic variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to patch CiviCRM to change this from a hardcoded constant into a setting.

Create a pull-request for this change and the core team will review it and merge it into 4.7.

See http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Settings+Reference

Comment: Just found your reference ten minutes ago and came here to self-answer ;) Thanks a load!

Comment: So will you be sending in a PR for this?

Comment: I'm just evaluating if I could add a new core setting without a dev installation. bin/regen.sh states that there's no setup.sh and as I read the script I saw it may truncate the database.
So may I manually add the setting to table civicrm_setting to enable it?

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7586