# Configure what gets added to recent items stack / Where to implement

Tags: developer, ui

For my organization it would be nice to define, what types of entities the "recent items" stack holds.

For example the list in the corresponding "recently viewed" widget gets flooded with the same activity entry when composing pdf letters for a group of contacts.

So it would be beneficial if there would be a configuration option to decide which entities/actions to include in the recent items stack.

This is related to [recently viewed items stack: Add a configuration option for MAX_ITEMS in Recent.php](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/recently-viewed-items-stack-add-a-configuration-option-for-max-items-in-recent) and should be treated together.

I'll investigate how to accomplish this, but I appreciate any hint about the more advanced civi programmers would integrate this. Should I add a new configuration form? Should I extend `CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Miscellaneous`?

Thanks in advance // nielo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to extend the class - there's a hook for this, [hook_civicrm_recent](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_recent).

Comment: Thank you. Because @coleman just pointed me to the settings reference, I'll decide walking the core road or the extension road while doing the implementation and see if our solution may be useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for a starting point on how to add settings/configuration options, see @coleman's hint to [civicrm's settings reference](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Settings+Reference) on https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8694/321

Comment: Together with http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8478/recently-viewed-items-stack-add-a-configuration-option-for-max-items-in-recent?lq=1 treated in pr https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7586